# OpenGL 4 GLSL 1282 INVALID OPERATION SIMPLE CODE

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

my problem is not properly drawing simple plane;
I dont know why i get once error at begining : Invalid Operation 1282.
Can someone check that?

My variables : 
`GLfloat *tab` for verticies plane 
`int *tab2` for indecies

this is my init funcion:

```
// kolor tła - zawartość bufora koloru
glClearColor( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

// wczytanie shaderów i przygotowanie obsługi programu
program=LoadShaders("shader.vert","shader.frag" );

//Vertexy
//VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

//Verticies;
glGenBuffers(1, &Verticies);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Verticies);
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,foo*sizeof(GLfloat), tab, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

unsigned int m_ciezarkow[]={0,1,0};


//Indicies
glGenBuffers(1,&Indeksy);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,Indeksy);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int)*size, tab2, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 



glUseProgram( program );

pos_cam=glGetUniformLocation( program, "camera" );
pos_color=glGetUniformLocation( program, "_color" );

glUseProgram(0);
```

This is my draw function:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glUseProgram(program);
//my camera
glUniformMatrix4fv(pos_cam,1,GL_FALSE,&cam.matrix()[0][0]);

//Verticies
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Verticies);
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3 , GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

//Masa
//glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
//glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Masa);
//glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 3 , GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

//Indicies
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,Indeksy);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,size,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(void*)0); 
glUseProgram( 0 );
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);`
```

Comment: I would start by figuring out which line is giving you the error. If you move the call to `glGetError()` to different places in your code, can you figure out the exact line?

Comment: I get this error after first loop draw function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mistake here:

```
//Indicies
glGenBuffers(1,&Indeksy);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,Indeksy);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int)*size, tab2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

You bind `Indeksy` as `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, but it should be `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`. With your code, there is probably 0 bound as index buffer, and the `glBufferData` for that target will fail with `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`.

Comment: I Love You MAN !
I Lost 2 hours of life, probably cuz i'am codding since morning;